# How to access a value of the array present in useEffect, in the return function of the functional component in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, foreach, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am trying to access symbol, companyName, latestPrice, changePercent, marketCap of the temp_arr in return statement. But it giving the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'companyName' of undefined**. Please help me with this. This is what I have tried till now:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
```

let temp_arr=[];
const Abc = props => {

```
const {companyName, symbol } = props;
const [appState, setAppState ] = useState({})
useEffect(() => {
    const API_token = `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${symbol}/quote?token=pk_042790e0f6f844c1a08763c9a03dc892`;
    fetch(API_token)
      .then(
        function(response){
            return response.json();
          }
      )
      .then(
        function(data){
            console.log("vdhsb", data);
            temp_arr.push({symbol:data['symbol'], companyName:data['companyName'], latestPrice:data['latestPrice'], changePercent:data['changePercent'],marketCap:data['marketCap']});
            setAppState(data)
            console.log("hjv kikg", temp_arr[0].changePercent);

        }
      )
      console.log("temp", temp_arr);
}, [])


console.log("rutuja", props);
return (
    <>
        <p style={{color:"white"}}>{symbol}</p>
        <p style={{color:"white"}}>{temp_arr[0].companyName}</p>
    </>
);
```

}

export default Abc;

Comment: Because you need to put some loading condition. The component doesn't wait for  your ajax to be completed.

Answer (score 0):

Add some loader or default value like this:

```
const {companyName, symbol } = props;
const [appState, setAppState ] = useState({ companyName, symbol })
const [isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const API_token = `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${symbol}/quote?token=pk_042790e0f6f844c1a08763c9a03dc892`;
    fetch(API_token)
      .then(
        function(response){
            return response.json();
          }
      )
      .then(
        function(data){
            setIsLoading(false)
            setAppState(data)

        }
      )
}, [])


console.log("rutuja", props);
return (
    isLoading ? <ShowSomeLoader /> : <>
        <p style={{color:"white"}}>{appState.symbol}</p>
        <p style={{color:"white"}}>{appState.companyName}</p>
    </>
);
```